# Submit form content to department based on drop down selection

Tags: php, forms

I am 100% unskilled when it comes to PHP. In fact, I pretty much took this code from another site which shares stuff with the world. I'm creating a simple website for my neighborhood pool and we have to addresses, one for membership questions and one for general questions.

What I would like is for the form to be sent to one of these emails based on the type selected in the drop down field.

My contact form HTML is below:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
Question Type:<br>
<select name="cf_dept">
<option>General</option>
<option>Membership</option>
</select><br>
Your name<br>
<input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
Your e-mail<br>
<input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
Message<br>
<textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

My php is:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'email address';
$subject = 'Message from website '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'http://website.com';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to email@provider.com');
    window.location = 'http://website.com/';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I have read through a number of websites including here but the language was really beyond my capability to comprehend so I apologize if this is an easy fix. If someone could let me know what I need to do using the simplest terminology possible I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: I'm not having an error using the code above. I'm sorry if I was unclear. The issue is that with the above .php code I can only submit the form to a single address. What I would like to happen is have the form be submitted to one email address if the "General" selection is made and have it submitted to another email if "Membership" is selected on the form.

So basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to do like a conditional such that if the "cf_dept" value is "general" the form data will go to email #1 and if it is :Membership" it would go to email #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `contact.php` script expects that you change the email it will send to.

```
$mail_to = 'email address';
```

In your case, you just have to do an `IF` statement to see which email the user is referring to, and alternate as you want.

Just below your `fields` definitions, you need to add another one which will get the value inside `<select name="cf_dept">`.

```
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
$field_dept = $_POST['cf_dept'];

if($field_dept == "Membership"){
    $mail_to = 'your membership email';    
}else{
    $mail_to = 'your general email';    
}
```

Comment: You're a rockstar. Thanks so much. Unfortunately I do not have sufficient rep on the site to upvote your comment.